# Convert list to python dictionary according to its position in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a list like this:

```
c = ['A','B','C']
```

and I want it to convert it into `dict` object like

```
d = {"alphabets":{"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C"}}
```

I have currently implemented the following code:

```
c = ["A","B","C"]
d={}
for i in range(len(c)):
    d.update({"alphabets":{str(i): c[i]}})
print d
```

But this gives the output `{'alphabets': {'2': 'C'}}`. Does anybody know how to deal with this bug?

Comment: Do you want the order i.e `0,1,2,3` as posted above- then mind dictionary does not cares about the order

Comment: May I ask why you want that? As it is, I see no point to it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am also asking myself why would one create a dictionary with integers as keys like in this example. Having a list is much simpler and one can still access the list items by their index: `my_list[0]` is easier to manage than `my_dict['0']`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I want to arrange the items in `list` by their `position` as a `key` in `dictionary`.

Comment: @abhi1610 They are already arranged in the list and you can access every item by its index. You can just put the list as a value for the key `alphabets`. It is important that a list can't be a key in a dictionary. You could have `d = {'alphabets': ['A', 'B', 'C']}`. Having a list you have many more possibilities, for example slicing: `d['alphabets'][::-1]` for reversing.

Comment: @abhi1610 I totally agree with cezar there is no need of dictionary here.

Comment: @cezar You are right it possible to index in `list` but with this example I can also add some attributes to `value` by referencing the `dict['key']` as subdictionary object

Comment: "I want to arrange the items in list by their position as a key in dictionary" is a repetition of what you're doing, not the reasoning of why you want to do it. It would be just as easy to add attributes to them in the `list` as it would in the dictionary, if you're still using that kind of "index" as a key. You can _already_ access them with `mylist[key]`. There is _no difference or improvement here_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are updating the dictionary.

**Warning:**

I have used normal dictionary. There is no orders in them you could use ordered dictionary if you want.

**Code:**

```
c = ["A","B","C"]
d={"alphabets":{}}
for i,v in enumerate(c):
    d["alphabets"][str(i)]=v
print d
```

**Output:**

```
{'alphabets': {'1': 'B', '0': 'A', '2': 'C'}}
```

**Notes:**

- The issue in your program  was you were always updating the key `alphabets` to a new dictionary.
- That is why you got `c:2` since that is the last updated dictionary
  -What I have done is created a dictionary with key `alphabets`

Comment: @abhi1610 happy to help.You could also use the other methods using dict comprehension which is faster but little untidy.

Comment: @The6thSense The dict comprehension is a way better, but your answer is more comprehensive for beginners. So, it is ok to iterate in a loop for a better demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with `dict comprehension`:

```
In [196]: {'alphabets': {str(i):v for i, v in enumerate(c)}}
Out[196]: {'alphabets': {'0': 'A', '1': 'B', '2': 'C'}}
```

If you need an order you could use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
l1 = [(str(i),v) for i, v in enumerate(c)]
d2 = OrderedDict(l1)

In [284]: d2
Out[284]: OrderedDict([('0', 'A'), ('1', 'B'), ('2', 'C')])

d = {'alphabets': d2}

In [286]: d
Out[286]: {'alphabets': OrderedDict([('0', 'A'), ('1', 'B'), ('2', 'C')])}
```

Or onliner suggested by @cezar:

```
d = {'alphabets': OrderedDict([(str(i), v) for i, v in enumerate(c)])}
```

Comment: @ Anton Protopopov -May i ask you a question why `The6thSense's` answer does not maintain order as your's does?

Comment: It is more important that `d['alphabets']` is an `OrderedDict`, not `d` itself.

Comment: I think it's just coincidence because dict isn't taking in acoount order of keys

Comment: @cezar yes, thanks. It's strange but with `OrderedDict` for that resulted `dict` I get `OrderedDict([('0', 'A'), ('2', 'C'), ('1', 'B')])` which I thought should be: `OrderedDict([('0', 'A'), ('1', 'B'), ('2', 'C')])`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov ordered dictionary keeps the order in which they are inserted. Since you have already created a dictionary it has no order in it.Try adding to an empty ordered dictionary.

Comment: You can put everything in one line: `d = {'alphabets': OrderedDict({str(i):v for i, v in enumerate(c)})}`. The import for this example should be: `from collections import OrderedDict`.

Comment: @cezar you forgot to sort it before passing to `OrderedDict`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov Yes, you're right. I saw that in your edit. I oversaw that the dict comprehension called as an argument to OrderedDict is still going to create just a plain unordered dictionary.

Comment: The oneliner can be made with a simple list comprehension: `d = {'alphabets': OrderedDict([(str(i), v) for i, v in enumerate(c)])}`. This way it should be sorted from the start on.

Comment: @cezar you're right it's simplier solution, thanks. Added to the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` too though it does not maintain **order**.

```
>>>{'alphabets':{k:v for k,v in zip(range(len(c)),c)}}
>>>{'alphabets': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}}
```

Comment: you could just use `enumerate` then zip and range.

Comment: @  The6thSense Yeah! ofcourse- more like `Anton Protopopov`.